# Inner join multiple ID columns with ID in foreign table to display multiple name columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, join

I need to make a query that inner joins 3 different id's from one table with the id from another, to then display the name value from that table in my select query. I'll try to make it a bit more clear.

In my one table I have these 3 columns with id's:

```
Book_Kalender.BS_ID,
Book_Kalender.BS_ID_Prio2,
Book_Kalender.BS_ID_Prio3,
```

These all need to be inner joined with a column in another table, which contains the name associated with these ids:

```
Book_Sommerhuse.[BS_ID]
```

In my SELECT query I am including the name column from the foreign table. I want to instead have 3 columns, each with the associated name that corresponds to the ID.

```
Book_Sommerhuse.BS_Navn
```

So far I have tried to make multiple inner joins using the AND keyword:

```
INNER JOIN Book_Kalender ON Book_Sommerhuse.[BS_ID] = Book_Kalender.[BS_ID] 
AND Book_Sommerhuse.[BS_ID] = Book_Kalender.[BS_ID_Prio2]
```

But this returns and empty view from my select query. I'm also not sure how to create new columns for each name associated with the ID.

Full query:

```
SELECT
    Book_Kalender.BK_ID,
    Book_Kalender.BK_DatoFra,
    Book_Kalender.BK_DatoTil,
    Book_Kalender.BK_M_Navn,
    Book_Kalender.BK_M_Adr,
    Book_Kalender.BK_M_PostBy,
    Book_Kalender.BK_M_Afd,
    Book_Kalender.BK_M_MedArbNr,
    Book_Kalender.BK_M_Tlf,
    Book_Kalender.BK_M_Email,
    Book_Kalender.BK_Tidl_Lejet,
    Book_Kalender.BK_Tidl_Lejet_Txt,
    Book_Kalender.BS_ID,
    Book_Kalender.BS_ID_Prio2,
    Book_Kalender.BS_ID_Prio3,    
    A.BS_Navn as BS_Navn1,
    B.BS_Navn as BS_Navn2,
    c.BS_Navn as BS_Navn3,
    coalesce(A.BS_Navn,B.BS_Navn,c.BS_Navn) as BS_Navn    
FROM
    Book_Kalender
    LEFT JOIN Book_Sommerhuse A ON 
        Book_Kalender.BS_ID       = A.BS_ID
    LEFT JOIN Book_Sommerhuse B ON 
        Book_Kalender.BS_ID_Prio2 = B.BS_ID
    LEFT JOIN Book_Sommerhuse C ON 
        Book_Kalender.BS_ID_Prio3 = C.BS_ID    
WHERE
    Book_Kalender.BK_DatoFra BETWEEN #10/15/2017# AND #12/31/2018#;
```

Comment: Do the Ids on the Book_Kalender table all refer to the same Name or different names?

Comment: I think your Book_Kalendar table needs normalising - whenever you find yourself storing the same thing in multiple columns within the same table, it's time for a sub-table containing those IDs, with a foreign key back to the parent table.

Comment: They are different ids, so they refer to different names in the Book_Sommerhuse table.

Comment: @Leth Then use a LEFT JOIN, see my answer below

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it is not possible to normalize this table as it needs to be imported to an SQL database very soon. I am trying to create a select statement which matches the structure in the table I am importing into.

Comment: ok that's a shame, the structure of your target table is less than ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You need 3 left join :

```
select
    Book_Kalender.*,
    A.BS_Navn as BS_Navn1,
    B.BS_Navn as BS_Navn2,
    C.BS_Navn as BS_Navn3,
    coalesce(A.BS_Navn,B.BS_Navn,c.BS_Navn) as BS_Navn -- first non null BS_Navn
from      
    Book_Kalender
    LEFT JOIN Book_Sommerhuse A ON 
        Book_Kalender.BS_ID       = A.BS_ID
    LEFT JOIN Book_Sommerhuse B ON 
        Book_Kalender.BS_ID_Prio2 = B.BS_ID
    LEFT JOIN Book_Sommerhuse C ON 
        Book_Kalender.BS_ID_Prio3 = C.BS_ID
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to implement your code, but I am getting a "Missing operator error" in relation to Book_Kalender.[BS_ID] = B.[BS_ID_Prio2]

Comment: check your columns names, you can remove bracket

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I have added my full query to my original post. I removed the brackets from the column names.

Comment: If it's ok remove the full query from your original post. Have you find the error ?

Comment: I am getting a missing operator error with this piece of the query: https://i.imgur.com/W4qcg8n.png

Comment: try just this query : select count(*) FROM
    Book_Kalender
    LEFT JOIN Book_Sommerhuse A ON 
        Book_Kalender.BS_ID       = A.BS_ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156925/discussion-between-indent-and-leth).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     K.BS_ID
    ,S1.BS_Navn
    ,K.BS_ID_Prio2
    ,S2.BS_Navn 'Prio2_BS_Navn'
    ,K.BS_ID_Prio3
    ,S3.BS_Navn 'Prio3_BS_Navn'
FROM
    Book_Kalender   K
LEFT JOIN
    Book_Sommerhuse S1 ON S1.BS_ID = K.BS_ID
LEFT JOIN
    Book_Sommerhuse S2 ON S2.BS_ID = K.BS_ID_Prio2
LEFT JOIN
    Book_Sommerhuse S3 ON S3.BS_ID = K.BS_ID_Prio3
```

Comment: I am running this query using MS Access, so the syntax is slightly different. Sorry for not making that clear in my post. As I understand, I need to enclose the first join clause in parentheses to logically separate it from the others, but it throws a "missing operator" error still.

Answer (score 0):

Use could use  derived table which could provide you three columns data as a single column and then you could apply the join , something like this

```
INNER JOIN (
              SELECT BS_IDs FROM Book_Kalender CROSS APPLY(
               VALUES (BS_ID), (BS_ID_Prio2), (BS_ID_Prio3)) Cols(BS_IDs) 
           ) DerivedBook_Kalender   ON Book_Sommerhuse.[BS_ID] = DerivedBook_Kalender.[BS_IDs]
```